# Can I change language setting in bulk for printouts inside OneNote?

Tags: language, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I do research and therefore sometimes move a whole book from PDF into OneNote using the Print to OneNote feature in order to annotate those books. The original is in PDF/A, thus searchable inside Adobe Reader. I would like those pages to be searchable inside OneNote as well, in order to save me the trouble of looking it up in the PDF file (a matter of expediency and efficiency). This is no problem when the book is in English because OneNote will eventually make the graphical object recognize text. However, that does not seem to be the case when I insert a book in a foreign language (i.e. Japanese, one of the recognized languages).

I usually have the book as its own section in OneNote, and it might then contain 200 or more pages. As it is now I go through each page individually, select the object (book page), right click it, select "Make text in image searchable" and then select the language. This is rather time consuming. So my question is if I can do this using some macro, or select the whole section and make those images searchable in another language. Or if there is a better strategy involved when I do the print to OneNote procedure in Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would to upload a notebook to OneDrive and then add the files you want to be converted to searchable text. It will automatically convert new content to searchable text like you want. Here is the article that describes this feature that was added earlier in the year.

http://venturebeat.com/2015/02/19/microsoft-updates-onenote-with-ocr-support-across-all-platforms-ipad-app-gets-handwriting-support/

As far a writing a macro that would be rather difficult and would require a host application to run it such as Excel. and you would have to connect the XML and OneNote libraries to your script.

Comment: Actually the notebook already exist in OneDrive. I just don't believe that the OCR will figure out the language on its own. Because not a single page has been recognized since I started the notebook several weeks ago.

Comment: Did you to create a new notebook and then upload the images?

Comment: Yes, I started with a new notebook in OneDrive, then I began importing PDF goes through the print to OneNote printer driver.